# problem using doGet(e) in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, get, query-string, http-status-code-400

I'm facing a doGet(e) problem.

The code I'm using is given below. Whereas the first part - getRecords is working fine, the second part getPwd is giving problem. I'm getting the error "Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1"
Where I'm going wrong?

```
//Get Records
function doGet(e){
  var action = e.parameter.action;
  if(action == 'getRecords'){
  return getRecords(e);
}
 if(action == 'getPwd'){
  return getPwd(e);
 }
}

function getRecords(e){
var returnrecords={};
var rows = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
data = [];
//Push all records to returnrecords
for (var r = 0, l = rows.length; r < l; r++) {
  var row = rows[r], record = {};
  record['email']    = row[2];
  record['username'] = row[3];
  record['id']    = row[4]; 
  record['phone']    = row[4];
  data.push(record);
 }
records.items = data;
var result=JSON.stringify(returnrecords);
return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
 }

function getPwd(e){
 var returnrecords={};
 data = [];
 var record = {};
 var eMail = e.parameter.eMail;
 var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var pWd = "";
 for(var i=0, iLen=values.length; i<iLen; i++) {
   if(values[i][2] == eMail) {
   pWd = values[i][7];
   }
 }
 record['password'] = pWd;
 data.push(record);
 records.items = data;
 var result=JSON.stringify(returnrecords);
 return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
 }
```

Also, what should be the query string in this case as I need to pass a parameter - eMail? I'm calling this from an Android app. The first case is to list all records.

Comment: What part of `getPwd(e)` is throwing the error?

Comment: This is the error " Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know."

Comment: It should be `?email=SomeEmail@example.com`

Comment: Problem is resolved after using Postman to check the posting. Also, the suggestion by The Master - "?email=SomeEmail@example.com" has helped. It was showing that there is error in line - records.items = data; (records not defined). How it is working in the first case (getRecords) with out errors?